# iOS UICollectionView: How to become notified once animation stops if cell is selected through code?

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, delegates, uicollectionview

UICollectionView, being a descendent of UIScrollView, sends to the UIScrollView delegate

```
scrollViewDidEndDecelerating
```

which is convenient to get notified when the scrolling motion, initiated by a swipe user interaction, stops.

however, if the selection of the cell is invoked through code by a call to

```
selectItemAtIndexPath
```

then scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is not called.

How can I get notified about the selection animation having stopped if I select the cell through code?

Comment: are u selecting a cell while scrolling your collection view?

Comment: No - there are two ways of selecting a cell in my application. Through user swipe interaction and by some other functions that cause automatic scrolling to a certain cell. I need to get notified about when the automatically initialised scroll animation has finished

Comment: are none of the UIScrollview delegate beside scrollViewDidEndDecelerating being invoked at all when doing programmatically a selection?

Comment: no, the documentation for selectItemAtIndexPath also states that it does not invoke the delegates

Comment: i see :-( may be can you explain how you want to make use of this notification: scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. They might be a work around depending of the context.